# CRLF behind the last line of a text file

Tags: c#, newline

How can I avoid CRLF character behind the last line in a text file, please?

> Header**LF**
>       Start_one**LF**
>       Start_two**LF**
>       Start_three**CRLF**

The source:

```
 string s = "\nStart_";
 StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder();
 txt.Append("Header");

 StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();

 row.Append(s + "one");
 txt.Append(row);
 row.Clear();
 row.Append(s + "two");
 txt.Append(row);
 row.Clear();
 row.Append(s + "three");
 txt.Append(row);
 row.Clear();


 using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\***\test.txt"))
 {       
     sw.WriteLine(txt.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: `.Write()` instead of `.WriteLine()`

Comment: Aaaa, thank you very much. :)

Comment: Let .net do the job for you: `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\***\test.txt", txt.ToString());`